# How can I have network sites not use year/month folders by default?

Tags: multisite, uploads

When creating a new network site, by default the site option `Uploads Use Yearmonth Folders` is on (set to `1`). I have to set it to `0` each time I create a new site. This isn't horrid, but is it possible to make this the default for newly created sites? Perhaps a hook or something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just change the option after the blog is created:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', function($blog_id){
  switch_to_blog($blog_id);
  update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);
  restore_current_blog();
});
```

Drop this code into a .php file inside wp-content/mu-plugins

Comment: Awesome, knew I had to be missing something wpmu-related. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question.  Are you referring to URLs?  If so go to Settings > Permalinks and adjust from there.

Comment: No, not the URL. It's the option to sort uploads into year/month folders, which is on by default for new sites in a multisite setting and there's no media setting to turn it off. I have to set it either in the DB or in the network admin site settings screen (which is really just a light DB GUI).